# The configured execution strategy 'SqlRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user-initiated transactions

Tags: asp.net, docker, backgroundworker, nservicebus

I have ASP.Net 4.7.2 window service which is processing NServiceBus messages. Currently it is deployed to On-Premise server. It has retry mechanism as well and working fine. Now I am going to containerizing it. While running into docker window container, it is doing SQL operation using Entity framework and giving exception as mentioned below:

The configured execution strategy 'SqlRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user-initiated transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retriable unit.

While running locally by installing manually or on On-Premise server, it is working fine but in container it is throwing exception.
Can any one help me what can be the root cause?

Comment: Can you maybe share some more details? For example, the ASP.NET configuration, the ASP.NET middleware that you use to create the transaction? Is this exception happening inside a controller action or inside a message handler? Can you provide the full stack trace? Then we can probably help better.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the piece of code does manual transaction management and is not wrapped within an execution strategy execute.

> if your code initiates a transaction using BeginTransaction() you are defining your own group of operations that need to be treated as a unit, and everything inside the transaction would need to be played back shall a failure occur.

> The solution is to manually invoke the execution strategy with a delegate representing everything that needs to be executed. If a transient failure occurs, the execution strategy will invoke the delegate again.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency#execution-strategies-and-transactions

```cs
using var db = new SomeContext();
var strategy = db.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

strategy.Execute(
    () =>
    {
        using var context = new SomeContext();
        using var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

        context.SaveChanges();

        transaction.Commit();
    });
``
```